# Using netcat for a Minecraft server

Tags: cmd.exe, netcat, minecraft

I have started learning the cmd code. While I was learning I have discovered netcat and that with it, you can make servers. I tried making a server for Minecraft likes this but it didn't work.

Here is what I wrote:

```
nc -l -p ip port.
```

This didn't work because when I ran the server it self it said that it failed to bind the port, and the port was the basic Minecraft port 25565.

I tried removing the `-p` because I saw it on a website but it turns out you must put the `-p` if you are on Windows. Can anyone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got confused with your terminology. In order to run a Minecraft server, you will need to download the [Minecraft server software](https://minecraft.net/download). Be aware there are more steps to perform than simply installing it, you would need to forward ports from your router correctly and allow related traffic to your firewall. You will find plenty of guides online for this.

A server, put *extremely* simply, is a centralised resource that clients connect to. When you are playing Minecraft, you use the client software to talk to a server. The server can't just be any program though, the clients will send requests to the server and the server will handle this appropriately and send the correct response. Without the correct server software, the clients response will be handled incorrectly, if at all, and there would be no successful communication.

Every website you visit is hosted on a server, every email you send will go via a server. They are all catered towards their specific needs. Netcat would simply relay text, even if your Minecraft client did connect to it, it wouldn't be able to do anything.

To summarise, you won't get a Minecraft server through netcat. You get a Minecraft server using Minecraft's server software.

Comment: I portforwarded and the server works but my friend and me can't connect to my ip only I can connect to the router ip.

Comment: @NikolaZagorac You need to make sure he's using your external IP address (which is likely to change every few days, possible on a router reboot also). Visit a website like www.whatismyip.org to get your external IP. Then make sure your ports are forwarded correctly to the port the server is listening to, and you're forwarding to the correct IP address. Finally, you'll need to make sure any firewalls, software on your computer or built into the router, are allowing the relevant traffic.

Comment: never mind works now

Comment: Can you just tell me what nc servers are used for?

Comment: @NikolaZagorac I've never used it for anything more than testing a connection between two points, that the ports are open correctly etc. It can be used for whatever you can imagine, it can send text over a network, which could then be executed and the response sent back. You could use it as a crude SSH connection with almost no security. You could serve a single static web page. You can't really run Minecraft through it though :). [more reading here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat)